# Adding a new path when the updated data has additional sections

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've been working a lot on D3.js lately, and the more I use it, the more I feel like I'm doing everything wrong!

Currently, I am trying to make a pie chart that allows for the client to press a button and switch between the information being shown. It's setup like this:

```
var width = 600,
    height = 675;

var outerRadius = 300,
    innerRadius = outerRadius / 3,
    color = d3.scale.category10();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function (d) { return d.value; });

var pieData = pie(dataDefault);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + (outerRadius + 50) + ")");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -(outerRadius + 10))
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Distrubution of Default Usage");

svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(pieData)
  .enter().append("a")
    .attr("href", function (d, i) { return "" + dataDefault[i].label + "Stats.cshtml"; })
    .append("path")
    .each(function (d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
    .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius, 0))
    .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150))
        .append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.value + " hits"; });
```

It may be useful to note some features, clicking on a slice links to a page that has more information and that specific data. And they have a hover affect where the slices grow slightly.

The data starts as default, then a button switches it to "dataBrowser."

```
dataBrowser = [{ "label": "Edge", "value": 15 },
        { "label": "Chrome", "value": 65 },
        { "label": "Safari", "value": 30 },
        { "label": "Firefox", "value": 40 },
        { "label": "Other", "value": 40 }];

dataDefualt = [{ "label": "", "value": 25 },
        { "label": "", "value": 25 },
        { "label": "", "value": 25 },
        { "label": "", "value": 25 }];
```

I pass the new data into the pie function, and pass that into the svg.

```
    var newData = pie(dataBrowser);
    var newColor = d3.scale.category20c();
    svg.selectAll("a")
         .data(newData)
         .attr("href", "#")
         .select("path")
         .each(function (d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
         .transition()
         .attr("d", arc)
         .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return newColor(i); })
         .attr("title", function (d) { return d.value; });
```

(The updating of the title isn't working so just ignore that)
This successfully updates the size of each slice of pie, but doesn't add a new one for the new information. How do I add (and subsequently remove) pieces from my svg?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new element you need to **append** it, preferably in an "enter" selection:

```
var newSlices = svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(newData);

newSlices.enter()
    .append("a")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .append("path")

newSlices.attr("href", "#")
    .select("path")
    .each(function(d) {
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20;
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return newColor(i);
    })
    .attr("title", function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
```

Pay attention to the fact that the above snippet relies on the *magic behaviour* of the "enter" selection of D3 v2 and D3 v3, removed in D3 v4.x. In this new version, will have to set the attributes of the "enter" selection as well (or use a `merge()`).

Here is your working code with a button to call the update:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 300;

var dataDefault = [{
  "label": "",
  "value": 25
}, {
  "label": "",
  "value": 25
}, {
  "label": "",
  "value": 25
}, {
  "label": "",
  "value": 25
}];

var outerRadius = 100,
  innerRadius = outerRadius / 3,
  color = d3.scale.category10();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var pieData = pie(dataDefault);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + (outerRadius + 50) + ")");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -(outerRadius + 10))
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Distrubution of Default Usage");

svg.selectAll("a")
  .data(pieData)
  .enter()
  .append("a")
  .attr("href", function(d, i) {
    return "" + dataDefault[i].label + "Stats.cshtml";
  })
  .append("path")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var dataBrowser = [{
    "label": "Edge",
    "value": 15
  }, {
    "label": "Chrome",
    "value": 65
  }, {
    "label": "Safari",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "label": "Firefox",
    "value": 40
  }, {
    "label": "Other",
    "value": 40
  }];

  var newData = pie(dataBrowser);
  var newColor = d3.scale.category20();
  var newSlices = svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(newData);

  newSlices.enter()
    .append("a")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .append("path")

  newSlices.attr("href", "#")
    .select("path")
    .each(function(d) {
      d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20;
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return newColor(i);
    })
    .attr("title", function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now if I switch back, how do I remove the access path?

Comment: @RileyShaw You'll have to use an "exit" selection. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z6qgcuu9/